# Loop doesn't recognise a changing variable

Tags: java, loops

I am trying to ask the user if they want to continue inputting numbers to add to a total value

```
    int total=0; 

    char letter='y';

    while (letter == 'y');
    {
            Scanner userInput = new Scanner (System.in);
            System.out.println("Input your number");
            int number = userInput.nextInt();

            total=number+total;


            Scanner userInput1 = new Scanner (System.in);
            System.out.println("Would you like to continue? Input y/n");
            char letter = userInput1.next().charAt(0); //**This is where there is an error**

    }        
    System.out.println("The total of all the numbers inputted is "+total);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. You shouldn't have the `;` on line 5 (the `while` line).
2. It is more performance-efficient to initialize the `Scanner` only once, outside the loop.
3. On the last line in the loop, use `letter = ***` instead of `char letter = ***`. You already declared the variable `letter`.
4. Perhaps you should handle the `nextInt` line in case user typed a non-number.

Possible improvement:

```
int total=0;
char letter='y';
Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
while(letter == 'y')
{
    System.out.println("Input your number");
    int number = userInput.nextInt();
    total += number;
    System.out.println("Woud you like to continue? Input y/n");
    letter = userInput.next().charAt(0);
}
```

Comment: Didn't solve the problem I was stuck on but got rid of the final error sign. Thank you

Comment: What problem are you having? I have tested the code I wrote above, and it breaks when result is not 'y'. Also, edited to add one more point.

Comment: @Pemapmodder I upvoted 3 of your different answers upvote mine too man :P

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove `char`, because `letter` was already defined. Instead of

```
char letter = userInput1.next().charAt(0);
```

write

```
// char removed
letter = userInput1.next().charAt(0);
```

And also as Pemap said remove the `;` after the `while`

Basically your code should be similar to the following

```
while (letter == 'y') {
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Input your number");
        int number = userInput.nextInt();

        total = number + total;


        Scanner userInput1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Would you like to continue? Input y/n");
        letter = userInput1.next().charAt(0); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much :) just getting into java in school.

Comment: If you find the answer correct and useful you can upvote it and sign it as the accepted answer with the green flag. Thanks

Comment: @DavideLorenzoMARINO I upvoted it because it has a good explanation.

Answer (score 1):

2 problems. 1st) you have a ; in a while statement line. 2nd) you have already declared letter variable. No need to declare it again after asking for input the 2nd time. Hope it helps.

```
int total=0; 
char letter='y';
while (letter == 'y')
{
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Input your number");
        int number = userInput.nextInt();

        total=number+total;


        Scanner userInput1 = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Would you like to continue? Input y/n");
        letter = userInput1.next().charAt(0); //**This is where there is an error**
}        
System.out.println("The total of all the numbers inputted is "+total);
}
}
```